# laravel 4 updateExistingPivot with where clause not working

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, relationship

I have two models:

**user** and 
**resource**

And relation table is **resource_user**.

the fields in resource_user are:

> id | resource_id | user_id | another_id

I have this relation in user:

```
public function resources() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Resource')->withPivot(array(
            'value',
            'another_id',
        ));
    }
```

Now I want update my pivot table:

(in model user there is this code example)

```
$this->resources()->whereAnotherId(1)->updateExistingPivot($resource_id, array(
                            'value' => $value,
                            'updated_at' => new DateTime,
                        ));
```

The problem is the another_id.

If I have two entries in my relation table (resource_user) 
but with **different** another_id 's. in this example, laravel will update BOTH entries. But this is not what I want.
In this example only one entry should be updated (the entry with another_id = 1).
Is this a bug, or how can I update my pivot table (the sync() function won't work with my table setup here)..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `wherePivot()` instead. With `whereAnotherId(1)` you are targeting the table of `Resource` and not the pivot table...

```
$this->resources()->wherePivot('another_id', 1)
                  ->updateExistingPivot($resource_id, array(
                        'value' => $value,
                        'updated_at' => new DateTime,
                    ));
```

Comment: @lukasgeiter, Seems you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44519339/how-can-i-update-pivot-table-on-laravel

Comment: This does not seem to make sense. To use 'where' clause with 'updateExistingPivot' is not very useful. Because 'updateExistingPivot' cannot update multiple M:M relations at once. It can only update a single relation whose id is the first argument of this method.
$resource_id = $this->resources()->wherePivot('another_id', 1)->first();
$this->resources()->updateExistingPivot($resource_id, array(
                        'value' => $value,
                        'updated_at' => new DateTime,
                    ));